# Вывод категорий сайта с помощью PHP

Tags: php

Добрый день, делаю вывод меню на сайте с помощью такой PHP функции:

```
function tree_cat_menu($parent_id){ // Функция глючит, нужно доработать!!!
    // Выводит список категорий
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, parent_id, name, cnc FROM categories WHERE parent_id='$parent_id'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {

            $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            echo '<ul>';
            do
            {           
                echo '
                <li><a href="category.php?id='.$myrow['id'].'">'.$myrow['name'].'</a></li>';                                
                tree_cat_menu($myrow['id']);
            }
            while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));     
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
```

Вот результат ее работы:

[image: Категории]

Вроде все ОК, но если мы перейдем в подкатегорию "Одежда Для женщин", то увидим такую картину:

[image: Категории1]

Отрисовываются только подкатегории, той категории, в которую мы зашли. Как сделать так, чтобы генерировался весь список, как в первом варианте?

HTML код (первый вариант):

```
<ul><li><a href="category.php?id=1">Для женщин</a><br><ul><li><a href="category.php?id=2">Одежда</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=3">Аксессуары</a><br></li></ul></li><li><a href="category.php?id=4">Для мужчин</a><br><ul><li><a href="category.php?id=5">Одежда</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=6">Аксессуары</a><br></li></ul></li><li><a href="category.php?id=7">Для детей</a><br><ul><li><a href="category.php?id=8">Одежда</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=9">Обувь</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=10">Игрушки</a><br></li></ul></li><li><a href="category.php?id=11">Для дома</a><br><ul><li><a href="category.php?id=12">Постельное белье</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=13">Интерьер</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=14">Кухня</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=15">Уборка</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=16">Дача</a><br></li></ul></li><li><a href="category.php?id=17">Автомобильные аксессуары</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=18">Увлечения</a><br><ul><li><a href="category.php?id=19">Cантехника</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=20">Инструменты</a><br></li></ul></li><li><a href="category.php?id=21">Электроника и аксессуары</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=22">Спорт</a><br></li></ul>
```

Второй вариант:

```
<ul><li><a href="category.php?id=5">Одежда</a><br></li><li><a href="category.php?id=6">Аксессуары</a><br></li></ul>
```

Comment: Извините, но я ещё раз скажу: мне кажется, вам не стоит делать интернет-магазин при данном уровне знаний. Всё-таки, это приложение, которое будет отвечать за деньги.

Comment: Так и сделаю - забью на магазин

Comment: > Извините, но я ещё раз скажу: мне кажется, вам не стоит делать интернет-магазин при данном уровне знаний. Всё-таки, это приложение, которое будет отвечать за деньги.

а я советую не делать на заказ, но сделать для себя, хотя бы на локальном компьютере, чтобы как раз набраться необходимых знаний для дальнейшего развития...

Comment: Я делаю для саморазвития, не на заказ. поэтому возникает так много вопросов.

Comment: тогда продолжайте делать и изучать ) и продолжайте спрашивать (если вопросы адекватные)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас получается так, что вложенные теги `<ul>` попадают вне тега `<li>`, т.е. они не будут отображаться, попробуйте так:

```
echo '<li><a href="category.php?id='.$myrow['id'].'">'.$myrow['name'].'</a><br>';
tree_cat_menu($myrow['id']);
echo '</li>';
```

Comment: Попробовал, но результат остался прежним((((((((((((((

Comment: добавьте еще html код, что у вас сгенерировало

**p.s.** весь html код не надо кидать )

Comment: Добавил...

Comment: > Как сделать так, чтобы генерировался весь список, как в первом варианте?

ой, вопроса полностью похоже не прочитал )

- покажите теперь вызов функции tree_cat_menu()
- на втором скрине что за список под элементами?

Comment: Вызов функции происходит так - tree_cat_menu($parent_id);

На список не обращайте внимание

Comment: я предполагаю, вы просто вызываете функцию от той категории, которая выбрана, т.е. при переходе к категории вызывается как раз от выбранной категории.., а надо от общего предка )

Comment: и как это мне реализовать?

Comment: - посмотрите какой параметр передается когда не выбрана категория
- передавайте точно такой же параметр во всех случаях

**p.s.** я имею в виду не переменную $parent_id, а ее значение

Answer (score 1):

Основная ошибка в том, что вы постоянно обращаетесь к базе. Меню надо выбирать одним запросом. Отстраивать дерево можно по-разному, вот [один из вариантов](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4dt-qy8).

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю.

Answer (score -1):

Если именно для категорий, можете использовать [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/)

Comment: Спс, но пока хочу реализовать на PHP